# FactoryGirl/machinist equivalent in c#/.Net

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

Rails has very nice way to generate test data with factoryGirl/Machinist +Shoulda . 
from [factorygirl](http://thoughtbot.com/community/) site 
"Factory Girl provides a framework and DSL for defining and using factories to create data records for ruby test suites. The goal is to be less error-prone, more explicit, and all-around easier to work with than Rails’ fixtures." 
Does there exist something like FactoryGirl/machinist in .Net/c# for test data  ?

Comment: I don't see nbuilder as the same I'm afraid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I may be late to the party but you may want to look into the über simple and clean [FactoryGirl.Net](https://github.com/JamesKovacs/FactoryGirl.NET) by James Kovak. It may not cover all the factory_girl features but you may want to pitch in if you're interested enough.

Answer (score 9):

This is a shameless plug of my own project, but also a valid answer.  I just released [Plant](http://github.com/jbrechtel/plant) which tries hard to be a factory_girl for .NET.

Comment: Just getting started with Plant, but so far I like it a lot